# first-child selector in nested list

Tags: html, css

Can't figure out a way to select first and last `<li>` in each list.
List can go forever so selecting like this is not solution:

```
ul li ul li etc...
```

Anyone has idea how to solow this? Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/y03La7kw/8/

Comment: Use classes & ID?

Comment: which type of output you want?

Comment: Im sorry I am confused on what you are trying to do in regards to the jsFiddle. 

Have you tried using `first()` or `last()`. These will get you the first and last elements of the set so if you wanted I believe you could try `$("ul li").first()` and `$("ul li").last()` to get what you want.

Comment: to select the first child use `ul:first-child` - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: I think I get what you mean. You only want the first child. But what you have is everything within the first child is red. You want everything inside the first child to not take on the properties being passed onto them?

Comment: In your case i think you should add a  **class** for each first item in a List

Comment: UPDATED EXAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/y03La7kw/17/
issue is if selecting pseudo elements inside first and last child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
ul > li:last-child > a{
 color:blue;
}
ul > li:first-child > a{
 color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="">a</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">a</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">a</a></li>
              <li><a href="">a</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">a</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">a</a></li>
</ul>
```

Your problem here is your 'sub items'. They are inside the `li` so, everything are inside the 'first' `li` will be red.
What you need to do is to add `<a>` or `<span>` to your `li` content.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a default color if not already done so and overwrite the first child of each unordered list.

```css
ul li {
  color: black;
}

ul>li:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a
    <ul>
      <li>a
        <ul>
          <li>a</li>
          <li>a</li>
          <li>a</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>a</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>a</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This was the solution, but if i add span inside first li and try to modify its :after for first and last it stops working
Updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/y03La7kw/17/

Comment: You cannot change the requirements again and again. If you have a new situation, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Ok true, but did't expect this situation to change how css selectors work, wanted to make it more simple, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6nmtkfu5/)

You just have to use :first-child and :last-child pseudo selectors. And don't forget to provide default style for other li like,

```
ul li:last-child,
ul li:first-child {
  color: red;
}

ul li {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css is works fine.

The problem with your example is that the `<ul>` that is inside a `<li>` takes the fontcolor of its parent.
I've added something to your example so you can see that its working 
http://jsfiddle.net/y03La7kw/8/

Comment: Thanks thats true, but if I add pseudo elements and try to select these it is not behaving as you described. Do you have any idea? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/y03La7kw/21/

Comment: Thats because you do not use the '>' operator which only selects direct childs => http://jsfiddle.net/y03La7kw/22/

Comment: Read more about css selector here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: hm not sure what you mean, can you try to fix fiddle above?

Answer (score -1):

you can create n of list by using below concept

```css
ul > li:first-child{
  color: red;
}
ul > li:last-child{
  color: green;
}
ul > li > ul > li:last-child{
 color: pink;
}
ul > li > ul > li:first-child{
 color: yellow;
}
ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:last-child{
 color: orange;
}
ul > li > ul > li > ul > li:first-child{
 color: #999;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a
      <ul>
        <li>a
            <ul>
              <li>a</li>
              <li>a</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>a</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>a</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As i said list can go forever so this is not solution

Comment: what you want to implement... if you set the target to some li than you have to follow the same concept.. otherwise you need to use jquery to create dynamic structure